# How do I ensure a controller is retained until after it completes processing when converting to ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I use the following pattern in my app and am transitioning to ARC. Basically, an object retains an instance of a controller and releases that controller when it is notified through a delegate protocol that it has finished. I don't use an iVar/property b/c startProcess can be called N times to process N things.

Example below:

```
// start a process in a controller
- (void)startProcess
{
    MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] init];
    // set the delegate, the delegate is defined as (nonatomic, assign)
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller start];
}

// when the delegate is notified, release the controller
- (void)myControllerDidFinish:(MyController):controller
{
    // do something with results
    [controller release];
}
```

When the above implementation is converted to ARC, the controller is no longer retained after `startProcess` concludes so the processing doesn't occur and the delegate message is never received.

QUESTION: When converting my project to use ARC, how would the above implementation be modified to work correctly w/o creating iVars in the object instantiating the controller? There is a similar example in Apple's documentation to transition to ARC but it involves using blocks. I'd rather not replace the delegate protocol with completion blocks.

EDIT: added comment in code re how delegate is defined

EDIT: clarified first para to explain why an iVar/property to hold the controller won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, it is the controller's responsibility to retain itself while it completes a task. If your controller runs a task on a background thread, then it should automatically be retained by the instance of `NSThread`. If data is being fetched over the network using `NSURLConnection`, the controller should be retained as the `delegate`.

If you are not doing a task like this, you can use synthetic circular retains to retain the controller while the task is being carried out. This can be done by creating an object, I will call it `ObjectRetainer`, that simply has a `__strong id` property. When the controller begins its task, it should have a `__strong ObjectRetainer` instance variable that gets set to a new `ObjectRetainer` that retains the controller. This way, the controller is retaining an `ObjectRetainer` that is retaining the controller, thus preventing either one from being deallocated.

When the controller completes its task and has called all necessary delegate methods, it should set the `ObjectRetainer` instance variable to nil. This will release the `ObjectRetainer`, that in turn will release the controller.

The `ObjectRetainer` interface might look something like this:

```
@interface ObjectRetainer : NSObject {
    __strong id object;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) __strong id object;
@end
```

You should declare an ivar in the controller's header: `__strong ObjectRetainer _retainer`. Then, in the controller's `start` method:

```
- (void)start {
    ...
    _retainer = [[ObjectRetainer alloc] init];
    _retainer.object = self;
}
```

When the controller is done, simply set `_retainer` to nil:

```
- (void)performBackgroundTask {
    ....
    [delegate myControllerDidFinish:self];
    _retainer = nil;
}
```

Comment: Nice, this worked perfectly! It's kind of a hack but trivial to implement. I'm sure over time I will change the implementation to use blocks but for now this got things working.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just create an `NSMutableArray` instance variable, `pendingControllers`, and adding your controller there? Since arrays retain their members, your code would look like this:

```
// start a process in a controller
- (void)startProcess
{
    MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] init];
    // set the delegate, the delegate is defined as (nonatomic, assign)
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller start];

    if (pendingControllers == nil) {
        pendingControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [pendingControllers addObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}

// when the delegate is notified, release the controller
- (void)myControllerDidFinish:(MyController):controller
{
    // do something with results
    [pendingControllers removeObject:controller];
    if ([pendingControllers count] == 0) {
        // if ARC is enabled, remove the call to -release.
        [pendingControllers release], pendingControllers = nil;
    }
}
```

This avoids the problem. Completion blocks *are* the right answer, and they’re what Apple is using going forward, but this method will work for now.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but seems ugly. I am all for using blocks, this is just a big project and I'm trying to convert to ARC while rewriting as little code as possible. I also thought about adding a completion block to the controller and defining the current delegate handlers in blocks.

Comment: If it seems less ugly to you, you can use an `NSMutableSet` instead. Either way, you’ll solve the problem of the controller being released.

Comment: +1 b/c this would work but the answer from @alex worked better for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

more simply: make the controller a data member... @synthesized method will do the magic.